# getOptimalNewCameraMatrix() returns (0,0,0,0) for roi

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, computer-vision

I've provided all the code below, just in case I've missed an obvious problem. The snippet in question is the final line, the roi variable is returned as (0,0,0,0), and I can't for the life of me figure out why. The same code seems to run fine in other programs, what am I doing wrong?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob

# termination criteria
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

# prepare object points, like (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0) ....,(6,5,0)
objp = np.zeros((6*7,3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:7,0:6].T.reshape(-1,2)

# Arrays to store object points and image points from all the images.
objpoints = [] # 3d point in real world space
imgpoints = [] # 2d points in image plane.

img = cv2.imread('left01.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Find the chess board corners
ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (7,6),None)


print ret
# If found, add object points, image points (after refining them)

if ret == True:
    objpoints.append(objp)
    cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners,(11,11),(-1,-1),criteria) # tutorial was wrong here
    imgpoints.append(corners)

    # Draw and display the corners
    cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (7,6), corners,ret) # tutorial was also wrong here
    cv2.imshow('img',img)
    cv2.waitKey(500)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1],None,None)

img = cv2.imread('left12.jpg')
h,  w = img.shape[:2]
newcameramtx, roi=cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(mtx,dist,(w,h),1,(w,h))
```